# OS X Lion: Finder wouldn't show directory contents

Tags: osx-lion, troubleshooting, finder

OS X 10.7.2

After my MacBook is running for several days, Finder starts to refuse to show contents of some (most) directories. The file list is empty and the progress animation in the bottom right is displayed indefinitely.

Rebooting helps, but I don't like to reboot often.

I ran Repair disk and Repair Permissions with Disk Utility, but it did not help.

Any other way I can troubleshoot and fix that?

Comment: Since it's been a while without an answer here, consider asking this on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) if you are still having the problem.

Comment: Looks like that upgrade to 10.7.3 or 10.7.4 fixed this.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh please post that as an answer.

Comment: And then please accept that answer so this does not remain on the unanswered questions list.

Comment: Questions disappear from the unanswered Q list once upvoted once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It seems that upgrade to 10.7.3 or 10.7.4 fixes this.</strike>

Actually, no, just had this issue on 10.7.4 and was able to figure out the reason.

I have a VMWare Fusion VM, which exposes a NFS mount point. The problem with Finder happens when VM is offline but NFS is stil mounted.